Bird struct and other type of birds
I am learning Go and trying to write a Bird design in Go. Here is the code. How can I improve it?
bird/bird.go
package bird

import "fmt"

type Bird struct {
    weight float64
    colour string
    size   float64
}

func NewBird(weight, size float64, colour string) *Bird {
    return &Bird{
        weight: weight,
        colour: colour,
        size:   size,
    }
}

type FlyingBehaviour interface {
    Fly()
}

type SwimmingBehaviour interface {
    Swim()
}

type Eagle struct {
    *Bird
}

func (e *Eagle) Fly() {
    fmt.Println("Eagle is flying")
}

type Penguin struct {
    *Bird
}

func (p *Penguin) Swim() {
    fmt.Println("Penguin is swimming")
}

type Duck struct {
    *Bird
}

func (d *Duck) Fly() {
    fmt.Println("Duck is flying")
}

func (d *Duck) Swim() {
    fmt.Println("Duck is swimming")
}

main.go
package main

import (
    "basic/bird"
)

func main() {
    bird1 := bird.NewBird(6.5, 2.1, "brown")
    eagle := &bird.Eagle{Bird: bird1}

    bird2 := bird.NewBird(15.0, 1.2, "black and white")
    penguin := &bird.Penguin{Bird: bird2}

    bird3 := bird.NewBird(2.5, 0.8, "white")
    duck := &bird.Duck{Bird: bird3}

    eagle.Fly()
    penguin.Swim()
    duck.Fly()
    duck.Swim()
}


“How could I improve it?”  Hmmm, if only this struct could answer questions like: What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?

What do you mean? An African or European swallow?

This, to my eye, really isn't enough code to actually review as being a piece of go code. It's more a design review, of a hypothetical/learning exercise. In that sense, it's not really code one would write in golang.
What this code looks like is like you picked up some DTO's from a Java (or other traditionally OOP language) and transcribed them in to golang verbatim. Go's type embedding, however, isn't meant to be used as the primary tool for inheritance, like you are doing. It's meant for composition. If you structure your code like this, it won't take long before you find yourself fighting the language, writing endless boilerplate code when adding a new type just to keep it working the way you need. Let's first cover some of the core things that differ in go, especially if you're coming from a class-based OOP language:
Interfaces don't live along side the implementation
Interfaces do not live alongside the implementation. Duck-type interfaces mean that you have types, that export an interface in a package, and that consumers of a certain interface declare the interface they need. If a type exports that interface, the dependency requirement is met, and we're all good. An interface along side the implementation is just repeating what methods you're exporting (essentially). Let the user decide what they need instead. Look at this example:
package foo

type Bar struct {
    f *SomeConnection
    // some more stuff
}

func (b *Bar) GetUser(id string) (*dto.User, error) {
    // note dto is a bad package name, but I'm too lazy to pick a better name
    data, err := b.f.GetByID(id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // do some processing or whatever
    return user, nil
}

func (b *Bar) Update(user *dto.User) error {
    // implement
}

func (b *Bar) Save(user *dto.User) error {
    id, err := b.f.Save(user)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    user.ID = id
    return nil
}

Now, it's not uncommon (in fact, I'd argue it's more common than not) to have the code that is responsible for reading/fetching data to be separate from the code that reads/updates/delete data. Perhaps not so much in a simple web application, but for example the code I'm currently working on ingests data from a couple of different sources, stores and updates that data, but we also have an RPC API alongside it to query the data. The packages related to the RPC stuff don't need, and should not have access to the write methods, so these packages may look something like this:
package service

type UserStore interface {
    GetUser(id string) (*dto.User, error)
}

type UserSvc struct {
    db UserStore
}

func New(store UserStore) *UserSvc {
    return &UserSvc{
        db: store,
    }
}

func (u *UserSvc) GetUsers(ids ...string) ([]*rpctypes.User, error) {
    users := make([]*rpctypes.User, 0, len(id))
    for _, id := range ids {
        user, err := u.db.GetUser(id)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err // request failed, just return error
        }
        users = append(users, rpctypes.MapUser(user)) // convert to RPC type
    }
    return users, nil // response data
}

A request to the API's now cannot result in an update/creation of a new record in the store, and this service package ensures that the DB side of things is not coupled in any way to the API types, effectively decoupling our API types from the way we store the data internally. That's all well and good, but it has several more benefits. Say we want to unit test the service, we need only to look at the service package to see what its dependencies are, generate some mocks, and we're off to the races. We only mock the methods that we're actually using, too.
Packages, when interfaces live alongside the user, rather than the implementation become much, much more self-documenting, much easier to test, and a lot easier to maintain. If you were to add a method to the dependent interface (like UserStore in the example above), your code won't compile unless that method is implemented by the type your package is currently using, or your CI will fail because your tests don't mock the new method. It provides a very tight and fast feedback loop to ensure your code stays well tested and healthy as it grows. It's something that feels a bit strange at first coming from a class-based OOP language, but it quickly becomes natural and it is, IMHO, one of the best things about the way interfaces work in golang. If you want, you really ought to look in to tools like gomock. You can just annotate your interfaces/files with a single directive and have go generate generate mocks for you that can be used something like this:
package service_test
// note: the package name testing the service package receives the _test suffi
// this forces you to test using the exported methods only
// anything that cannot be covered this way is likely poor code

func TestGetUsers(t *testing.T) {
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    store := mocks.NewUserStoreMock(ctrl)
    defer ctrl.Finish()
    svc := service.New(store) // inject mock
    ids := []string{"foo", "bar"}
    // now we pass in 2 ids, so we expect 2 calls:
    // store.EXPECT().GetUser(gomock.Any()).Times(len(ids)).Return(&dto.User{}, nil)
    // or even:
    store.EXPECT().GetUser(gomock.Any()).Times(len(ids)).DoAndReturn(func(id string) (*dto.User, error) {
        return &dto.User{
            ID: id, // set the ID passed as argument in the call
        }, nil
    })
    users, err := svc.GetUsers(ids...)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.Equal(t, len(ids), len(users))
}

Now this test allows you not just to check if the dependency is called, but how many times, and even it allows you to control what it returns for each call, based on the known arguments you pass in. If the store dependency is called more than expected, the test will fail. If it doesn't get called as many times as you expect, the test will fail. If you want to test a fail scenario, then by all means, test it: just have the mock return an error at the desired moment:
func TestGetUsers(t *testing.T) {
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    store := mocks.NewUserStoreMock(ctrl)
    defer ctrl.Finish()
    svc := service.New(store) // inject mock
    ids := []string{"foo", "bar", ""} // last is empty string
    store.EXPECT().GetUser(gomock.Any()).Times(len(ids)).DoAndReturn(func(id string) (*dto.User, error) {
        if len(id) == 0 { // empty string, third call
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("fail at the third call")
        }
        return &dto.User{
            ID: id, // set the ID passed as argument in the call
        }, nil
    })
    users, err := svc.GetUsers(ids...)
    require.Error(t, err)
    require.Empty(t, users)
}

What we have now is fully testable, and by the nature of the types used, guaranteed read-only code, that's easy to understand just by looking at a single file (it declares the interface it depends on, and the tests demonstrate all of the expected behaviours).
Now you might say: neat, but you're expecting the store part to work as intended... to which I say: Yes, why wouldn't I? The responsibility of this package is to take a dependency that implements a given interface, and use it the way it wants to. I test to ensure that I'm using the interface correctly. Whatever implements the interface ought to be tested properly, and work as intended, too. The service unit is tested to show it works correctly. If the dependency doesn't work correctly, it's poorly implemented (and poorly tested), that's beyond the scope of a unit test.
Anyway, onwards with the review...
Embedding does not equal hierarchies
As I mentioned at the very start: you're embedding a Bird type, which in class-based OOP (simply going to use OOP from here on out) would probably be an abstract base class. It implements no interfaces, exports no fields, just has a contructor. It's sole purpose is to take in some arguments (passed to the constructor) and wrap them in a type that effectively groups and hides the values. A Bird is meaningless as a type outside of your package that also declares Eagle and Penguin. Because go doesn't have class hierarchies, there's no way for you to do something like:
p := bird.Penguin{
    Bird: bird.NewBird(args),
}
e := bird.Eagle{
    Bird: bird.NewBird(args2),
}
UseBirds(p, e)

func UseBirds(birds ...*bird.Bird) {
    // nope
}

In OOP, UseBirds would be able to use both a Penguin and an Eagle as a Bird, but in golang, a Penguin and an Eagle still are entirely distinct types. They just happen to embed the same third, but also entirely distinct type Bird. Embedding a type doesn't express a hierarchy. It's a constituent part. If you have a Person, and combine several of them in to a Household entity, that doesn't magically turn the Household entity into a child of Person. It just means that the Household will share (export/expose) some of the abilities (methods) of the constituent Persons, but the two entities are not interchangeable in any way. All it means is that you can't have a Household without a Person. It's more of a requires relationship than a is-a/inherits from relationship. On that basis alone, the Bird embedded in Eagle example makes no sense. An eagle is a bird, but an eagle does not require a bird.
Before we go on, I explicitly initialised a penguin and an eagle in the snippet above, to point out the horror that is your package, type, and constructor names. They stutter something awful. If you name your package bird, that's fine, but naming your constructor NewBird is downright evil: bird.NewBird() is totally redundant. Name the constructor New: brid.New(). It's easier to write, read, and conveys exactly the same information.
All in all, this kind of attempt at structuring types will always feel a bit like a square peg in a round hole type of deal, but if you want to create a bird package like this, I would definitely consider doing something like this:
type Base struct {
    // all shared fields go here
}
type Eagle struct {
    *Base
    // eagle-specific stuff
}
type Penguin struct {
    *Base
    // penguin stuff
}

// list all bird species here
type Species interface {
    Eagle | Penguin
}

func New[T Species](args) *T {
    return &T{
        Base: &Base{
            // initialise using args here
        },
    }
}

With this, getting a penguin and eagle would look something like this:
func main() {
    p := birds.New[birds.Penguin](args)
    e := birds.New[birds.Eagle](args)
}

This leaves you with 1 constructor, and a base bird type that the user doesn't have to be aware of. How and when to use the fly/swim interface stuff is something that cannot be definitively answered in a simple code review like this. That entirely depends on logic. You may have some kind of environment package, with aquatic specified, where you need a type that has a Swim method, but as mentioned earlier: those interfaces belong in those packages, and passing the wrong bird type there will cause the code to not compile. Now that we've ended up with a single constructor that returns distinct types of birds, passing an Eagle to some code that expects to be able to call bird.Swim() is clearly a bug that shouldn't have been written, and needs fixing, not something you use some kind of type system to circumvent or hide.
